# What are my options to avoid a Cross Origin Request being blocked?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, cors, client-side

### Situation:

I want to call --> [Food Hygiene API](http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities) and manipulate the result, before rendering.

I believed I could write this clientside in Javascript in a single page web app, avoiding the need for a full-stack application.

I ran into the 'Cross Origin Request Blocked' and subsequently discovered the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) followed by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

### I have subsequently tried:

A CORS request with this code (from [this source](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-introduction)):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  const ul = document.getElementById('authorities');
  const url = 'http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/json'

  function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url, true);
      return xhr;
  }

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);

  xhr.onload = function() {
    var responseText = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(responseText);
  }

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log("there was an error!");
  }

  xhr.send();  
});
```

A jQuery call with JSONP (that errors and returns no responseText from the target):

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/json',
      accept: "text/json",
      async:true,
      contentType: 'text/plain',
      dataType : 'jsonp',   
      crossDomain:true,
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
      },
      success: function(json) {
        alert("Success");
        console.log(json);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert("Error");
      },
    });
  }
```

From what I can tell, the target api *does not* support CORS, as the HTTP response pushes `xhr` to `error`, in both the vanilla and the jQuery example.

Have locally 'resolved' the issue with [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en), but I don't think that it will solve the problem for users that were to clone the repo, or use the page if it were hosted on, for example, Heroku.

### What are my options from here?

Comment: one option only if you don't have any control of the server ... proxy the request through your own server

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is trying to set the .withCredentials property to true before sending the XMLHttpRequest reference: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/.

Comment: Yeah, tried that but to no avail Mr Smith :/

Comment: You can do this:

    `const url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/json'`

…and it will work. For an explanation, see the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141